# Encontrar numeros en python 3.8.2

Tags: python, python-3.x

estoy haciendo un programa que encuntra los numeros que hay de entre esos dos

ejemplo:
si buscas un numero de 1 al 10 el programa te pone

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
```

y ahi finaliza el programa

pero cuando pongo dos numeros iguales el programa solo busca numeros desde el numero minimo hasta el infinito

este es mi codigo

```
def find_nums(num_start, num_finish):
    print(num_start)
    while True:
        num_start += 1
        print(num_start)
        if num_start == num_finish:
            break
        elif num_start == num_start:
            print(num_start)
            break
num1 = int(input("n1 : "))

num2 = int(input("n2 : "))

find_nums(num1, num2)
```

Answer (score 2):

El problema es que si son iguales, como incrementas `num_start` (`num_start += 1`) antes de la comparación (`if num_start == num_finish:`), al llegar a la comparación ya no son iguales y nunca lo serán porque `num_start` es ahora mayor que `num_finish` en una unidad.

La salvaguarda que has intentado usar `elif num_start == num_start` rompe el ciclo, pero lo rompe siempre que el primer `if` no se cumpla ya que lógicamente `num_start` es igual a `num_start` siempre.... Esto hace que se itere una sola vez...

De cualquier forma, no te compliques con los condicionales, simplemente usa la condición de control del ciclo `while`:

```
def find_nums(num_start: int , num_finish: int) -> None:
    while num_start <= num_finish:
        print(num_start)
        num_start += 1

num1 = int(input("n1 : "))
num2 = int(input("n2 : "))
find_nums(num1, num2)
```

No se si se trata de una tarea académica, por lo que lo siguiente se consideraría hacer "trampa", pero la forma correcta de hacer esto en Python sería usar un `for in` con `range`:

```
def find_nums(num_start: int , num_finish: int) -> None:
    for n in range(num_start, num_finish + 1):
        print(n)
```

o directamente:

```
def find_nums(num_start: int , num_finish: int) -> None:
     print(*range(num_start, num_finish + 1), sep="\n")
```